# Checking string, regex issue?

Tags: java, string, loops

Currently I am checking a string for the following:

```
if(parseCommand.contains("vlan1") || parseCommand.contains("Fa0/1i")
  || parseCommand.contains("Fa0/1o") || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/0")                              
  || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/1") || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/2")
  || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/3") || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/4")
  || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/5") || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/6")                                    
  || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/7") || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/8") 
  || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/9") || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/11") 
  || parseCommand.contains("Gi0")) {
//do things here                              
}
```

However it may contain vlan1 up to vlan4094 and i have to check for these. What is the simplest way to do this?

I have tried this just to match a vlan 1-9 folowed by 0-3 digits but it doesn't find anything:

```
if(parseCommand.matches(".*vlan[1-9](\\d){0,3}") || parseCommand.contains("Fa0/1i")
  || parseCommand.contains("Fa0/1o")|| parseCommand.contains("Fa1/0")                               
  || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/1") || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/2")
  || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/3") || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/4")
  || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/5") || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/6")                                    
  || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/7") || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/8") 
  || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/9") || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/11") 
  || parseCommand.contains("Gi0")) {
```

Even if I try this nothing is found, why?

`if(parseCommand.matches(".*vlan.*"`)

Comment: it should be enough `vlan[\\d]{1, 4}` I think. Can you give a sample command to test against?

Comment: What kind of command would you like? Any string that contains vlan1 - vlan4094, anything can come before or after

Comment: I could be missing something. But I'm not sure you should have those periods in the regex?

Comment: The regexp looks fine as `"vlan1".matches(".*vlan[1-9](\\d){0,3}")` returns `true`. Are you sure that parseCommand contains `"vlan1"` ?

Comment: I am sure because parseCommand.contains("vlan1") works fine. I tried both with and without  @MementoMori, neither worked, will try again. Nothing was found with vlan[\\d]{1, 4} method, perhaps it needs .*

Comment: parseCommand.matches("vlan1.*")  doesnt even work

Comment: @JoopEggen is onto something in his answer. Could you maybe have a line break or something similar in your string? Then his suggestion with `(?s)` would help.

Comment: Indeed it did work, but I'm not sure why some of the others did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.matches("(?s).*vlan.*")` or so for new line characters being catched by `.`; See [DOTALL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL).

Comment: This works thanks, I'm not sire why the other answers were not working?

Comment: You then had a newline character `\n` in the string and that is not matched by `.`. The command `(?s)` also matches `\n` for dot.

Comment: I see, and would that newline have to come directly before or after vlan to be affecting it, or would a newline anywhere in the string matter?

Comment: Without `(?s)` either the first `.*` does not match (if newline before "vlan", or the second `.*` if newline after "vlan". By the way, `\r` is matched by `(?s)` DOTALL too.